# How can I open Excel 2010 showing no worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I start Excel 2010, it comes up showing a blank spreadsheet. I often have no need for this, because I'm going to navigate to a specific directory and open a spreadsheet there. How can I start Excel without having it create a new blank spreadsheet?

I know I could use Windows Explorer to navigate to a directory and open the desired spreadsheet there, but sometimes I find it more convenient or more natural to open Excel first.

I'm running Excel 2010 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use command-line to prevent a new blank workbook from opening, but please note, it also prevents Excel startup screen from appearing.

1. Please right click on an empty space on the desktop > New > Shortcut > Browse > find **EXCEL.EXE** > OK > Next, then follow the prompts to finish.

   - For 32-bit Office 2010

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\

   - For 64-bit Office 2010

   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\

[image]

2. Right click the shortcut > Properties > Target, add " `/e`" at the end of the path > Apply > OK. Please note, there is a space before the slash. Then please double click the shortcut to open Excel to have a check.

[image]